# Initialiser Inheritance confusion

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, initialization

I am trying to build some mocking infrastructure, I want to be able to return a stubbed value and count the times the value was accessed. I have something simple like this:

```
class BasicMock<T> {

    var callsCount = 0
    private let backing: T

    var result: T {
        callsCount++
        return backing
    }

    init(result: T) {
        self.backing = result
    }

}

class MockTimeDefinitionSerialiser: BasicMock<[String: [AnyObject]]>, TimeDefinitionSerialiserProtocol {

    func serialiseTravelTime(travelTime: JSSTravelTime) -> [String: AnyObject] {
        return result
    }
}
```

However trying to build it:

```
let mockTimeDefinitionSerialiser = MockTimeDefinitionSerialiser(result: ["": ""])
```

Emits the error `'MockTimeDefinitionSerialiser' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initialisers`

My interpretation of the Swift docs is that I should automatically inherit the initialiser as I have set all stored properties.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please remove any unnecessary code when asking a question. I was able to reduce your problem to this:

```
class Base<T> {
    init(t: T) {}
}

class Sub: Base<Int> {}

Sub(t: 0)    // error: 'Sub' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initialisers
```

It seems like even though you specified the `T` in the subclass, the compiler cannot infer what the initialiser uses for `T`. I couldn't find a way to get the initialiser to be inherited, you'd have to use a workaround:

```
class Sub: Base<Int> {
    override init(t: Int) {
        super.init(t: t)
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i found this as well but not the most ideal solution.